# How can I run Gunicorn with NGINX (I want to move from Django development to test my production)?

Tags: django, nginx

This is for learning purpose. I have done the web application with Django + Celery/RabbitMQ. I tried to follow [this](http://tutos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/ndg.html) tutorial. I got everything set until **"That’s all for gunicorn."**. In sense, my Gunicors runs like what it is describe in the tutorial.

Now I am confused with the NGINX settings.

I have these configurations in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf in its http block.

```
    upstream awesome_app {
        server unix:/home/notalentgeek/Downloads/awesome_app/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=10s;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;

        client_max_body_size 4G;

        access_log /home/notalentgeek/Downloads/awesome_app/logs/nginx-access.log;
        error_log /home/notalentgeek/Downloads/awesome_app/logs/nginx-error.log warn;

        location /static/ {
            autoindex on;
            alias   /home/notalentgeek/Downloads/awesome_app/static/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                proxy_pass http://awesome_app;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything else there stay untouched.

And then what should I do after this? The tutorial does not way anything. How can I see my web application? Moreover how can I set NGINX for Docker ready?

EDIT: With Gunicorn is running or not, starting NGINX with `sudo service nginx start` gives this error.

```
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
sep 27 17:23:48 notalentgeek-ThinkPad-X220 nginx[28260]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/home/notalentgeek/Downloads/awesome_app/logs/nginx-access.log" failed (2: N
sep 27 17:23:48 notalentgeek-ThinkPad-X220 nginx[28260]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
sep 27 17:23:48 notalentgeek-ThinkPad-X220 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
sep 27 17:23:48 notalentgeek-ThinkPad-X220 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit nginx.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
sep 27 17:23:48 notalentgeek-ThinkPad-X220 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
sep 27 17:23:48 notalentgeek-ThinkPad-X220 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
sep 27 17:23:48 notalentgeek-ThinkPad-X220 sudo[28225]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to do anything else?

Comment: I want to see my web application in my browser running from NGINX + Gunicorn. How?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error and access log need to be created before hand. After this my website runs fine.